# Ошибка при нажатии кнопки Telegram Bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

При нажатии кнопки Addition, которая генерирует пример с арифметическим действием сложение пользователю, выходит вот такая ошибка

```
TypeError: math_operation() missing 1 required positional argument: 'args'
```

А вот сам код от бота

```
import telebot

bot = 'token'


@bot.message_handler(commands=['game'])
def user_message(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == '/game':
            markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, row_width=5)
            addition = types.KeyboardButton('➕ Addition')
            markup.add(addition)

            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Welcome!', reply_markup=markup)
        elif message.text == '➕ Addition':
            addition1 = (int(random.randint(1, 10)))
            addition2 = (int(random.randint(1, 10)))
            answer = addition1 + addition2
            args = (answer, )

            msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Solve the example:\n{int(addition1)} + {int(addition2)}')
            bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, math_operation, args=args)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def math_operation(message, args):
    answer = args[0]
    if int(message.text) == int(answer):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        buttons = [
            types.KeyboardButton(' Solve the example again'),
            types.KeyboardButton(' Back')
        ]
        markup.row(*buttons)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'The example is solved! ', reply_markup=markup)
    elif not int(message.text) == int(answer):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        buttons = [
            types.KeyboardButton(' Solve the example again'),
            types.KeyboardButton(' Back')
        ]
        markup.row(*buttons)

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'The example is unresolved! ❌', reply_markup=markup)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.infinity_polling()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделай так

```
bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, math_operation, args)
```